# Spring CrudRepository method findAll() returns an empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

So, my problem is in the title - crudrepository method `findAll()` returns a null list. I've overriden Crud's method because it returned an iterable instead of a list.

I've tried using the `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` (I didn't override the `findAll()` method then), but got the same result.

My code:

Event.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Event{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private City city;

}
```

City.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long code;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Event> events;
    }

CityRepository.java

    @Repository
    public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {
    
    @Override
    List<City> findAll();
}
```

EventsController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class EventsController {

    @Autowired
    static CityRepository cityRepository;

    public static List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @RequestMapping
    public String eventEntry(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("event", new Event());
        model.addAttribute("cities", cityRepository.findAll());
        
        return "eventEntry";
    }
}
```

eventEntry.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Event entry</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>New event</h3>
    
    <form method="POST" th:object="${event}">
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City: </label>
            <select th:field="*{city}">
                <option value="" >Choose a city</option>
                <option th:each="city : ${cities}" th:value="${city}" th:text="${city}"></option>
            </select>
            <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}" th:errors="*{city}">City Error</span>
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
            <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="time">Time: </label>
            <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{time}" />
            <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('time')}" th:errors="*{time}">Time Error</span>
        </div>
                    
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" th:value="Save">
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>
```

I am using an embedded H2 database with a `data.sql` file used to fill data into the database (I don't have the `schema.sql` file since tables are created using annotations).
When viewing the H2 database console and using the `SELECT * FROM CITY` I'm getting the list of the cities.

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on this line from the EventController class: `model.addAttribute("cities", cityRepository.findAll());`
Can someone explain why?

Comment: findAll() doesn't return a null list. You get a NPE because `cityRepository` is null. Spring will never, ever, ever autowire a static field. Don't make assumptions. Use your debugger, or traces in the code to understand what is happening.

Comment: what an oversight... i simply deleted the `static` declaration in front of the repository and it works now... I will look much harder into my own code in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the `static` declaration in front of the repository, it works fine now